# Can I update an existing Lead using a Web-To-Lead form?

Tags: web2lead, website-integration

My client has Salesforce Professional Edition. I have web-to-lead form that can add new leads, but it does not seem able to update leads that already exist.

Is there any way, without a Salesforce upgrade, to update information for an existing Lead?

Right now, we are populating the IDStatus field with something like "Warm Lead" if a user fills out a basic newsletter-type form (Name, email, phone). If they fill out a more substantial form, which includes a deposit, we want to treat them differently in Salesforce.

My initial assumption was that we would be able to just reassign the value of the IDStatus field, and we'd be good to go. However, that is not working.

I just want to be able to filter leads differently depending on the most recent action they have taken on our website. And it seems like this should be doable without upgrading Salesforce...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to this:

> Right now, we are populating the IDStatus field with something like "Warm Lead" if a user fills out a basic newsletter-type form (Name, email, phone). If they fill out a more substantial form, which includes a deposit, we want to treat them differently in Salesforce.

What you will need is an assignment rule. In order to treat them differently, let's say you may like to assign Leads with value as "Warm Lead" leads to a specific queue with specific Sales reps so that they can be targeted differently. Refer more on the assignment rules on the [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_assignment_rules.htm&type=5).

In response to this:

> Is there any way, without a Salesforce upgrade, to update information for an existing Lead?

Edit:
You will need an upgrade from edition perspective, if you want to implement triggers. You may want to implement a rule to identify if a Lead already exists then take some action. The trigger will take care before operating on the incoming Lead and based on the logic to identify existing Lead, to merge the information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you saying that making any changes to an existing Lead requires an upgrade in Salesforce editions? We apparently have 5 "Process Builders" at our disposal as part of Professional Edition. Could we use those to make any changes to the existing Lead data?

Comment: Hi Jeremy - if at all you have to use custom options viz., apex, triggers, then yes. However if you have Process Builders available, then yes you can always create a process to make sure after the leads are received, what are the actions you need to perform on those.